# How to find bursts in time series using the Bursts package in R

Tags: r, time-series, anomaly-detection

I've tried doing burst detection with the [bursts](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bursts/index.html) package. I'm doing this because I want to find spikes in a time series.

When I do `kleinberg(ts)` it says:

```
Error in kleinberg(ts) : 
  Input cannot contain events with zero time between!
```

The time series is:

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 120 
Frequency = 1 
  [1]   5   5   5   5   5  14   4   8  11  11  11   4   7   3  10   7  13   6   3   3   6   9   9  12   6   6   9   3   9
 [30]   6  12   3   3   3   6   9   6   3   3   4   6   6   6   3   6   7   9   9   6   6  15   9  21   9   9   9   9  12
 [59]   6  12   3   3  17   9   9   9   9  12   3  12   3   3  13  13   3   7   6   6   6   9  10   3   7   6  16   3   9
 [88]   9   9  17  12   9   9  19  20  13  13  16  17  11  14  20  15  14 100  70  20  15  26  44  20  19   8  38  14  15
[117]  11   6  19  21
```

The output of `dput(ts)` for one particular time series I'm interested in is

```
structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 100L, 
78L, 21L, 13L, 15L, 12L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Tsp = c(1, 
120, 1), class = "ts")
```

Comment: it works fine for me when I use `ts <- ts(1:120, frequency = 1)`. you might want to add add the output, e.g. by using `dput(ts)`.

Comment: @epo3 I supplied the output to `dput(ts)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `kleinberg` needs the subsequent values to change, see the [function code](https://gist.github.com/ikegami-yukino/fb5fa79fde91ca0bbe98#file-kleinberg-py-L24). In your time series there are cases where you have a series of the same numbers.

When I tried using `kleinberg(unique(ts))`, it worked fine.

Also, using a randomly generated time series, `kleinberg()` worked fine:

```
ts2 <- as.ts(rnorm(1000,mean=1,sd=10))
plot(ts2)
burst <- kleinberg(ts2)
plot(burst)
```

[image]

It's possible that `kleinberg` in the default form might not give you what you need but you might find Twitter's [AnomalyDetection](https://blog.twitter.com/2015/introducing-practical-and-robust-anomaly-detection-in-a-time-series) package useful.